# 1987 isuzu pup can't turn main cog for timing

Tags: isuzu, cam-timing

I'm trying to realign my jumped timing I have the crankshaft aligned I just can't get the main cog to turn any further than where its at I have removed the sparkplugs and everything but it still only turnsto a certain point and won't make a full rotation  [image: this is where its at]

Comment: You're probably hitting valves you need to turn the cam and crank at the same time or set the cylinders in a position so that all cylinders are in the same position and you can reset your cylinder 1 valves at TDC. Can you provide a picture of the crank position and marks as well? in the pic your cam gear is 180° off so I'm guessing you're on the exhaust TDC stroke.